# SQL Server : count XML Children within Parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Hi I have been looking for a way of updating xml produced in sql to add the count of child nodes and add the count to the parent node using SQL

I've tried various workings around

```
    SET @xml.modify
    (
       'insert attribute TrCount {count(/XML/Acs/Act/Trs/Tr)} into (./XML/Acts/Act/Trs)'
```

);

```
    <XML>
      <Id>12</Id>
      <DateCreated>2013-04-11</DateCreated>
      <Acts AccountCount="4">
        <Act RowID="1>
             <Trs>
                 <Tr RowID="1" />
             </Trs>
         </Act>
         <Act RowID="2">
             <Trs>
                 <Tr RowID="1"  />
                 <Tr RowID="2" />
             </Trs>
          </Act>
          <Act RowID="3">
             <Trs>
                 <Tr RowID="1"/>
             </Trs>
          </Act>
          <Act RowID="4">
             <Trs>
                 <Tr RowID="1" />
                 <Tr RowID="2" />
                 <Tr RowID="3" />
                 <Tr RowID="4" />
                 <Tr RowID="5" />
                 <Tr RowID="6" />
                 <Tr RowID="7" />
           </Trs>
             </Act>
      </Acts>
    </XML>
```

above is a sample, I have got it to give me a count of  within  but I can not seem to get a count of each  within each ,  so the result would look like

```
    <Act RowID="1>
          <Trs  Trcount="1">
            <Tr RowID="1" />
          </Trs>
        </Act>
        <Act RowID="2">
          <Trs  Trcount="2">
            <Tr RowID="1"  />
            <Tr RowID="2" />
          </Trs>
        </Act>
        <Act RowID="3">
          <Trs Trcount="1">
            <Tr RowID="1"/>
          </Trs>
        </Act>
        <Act RowID="4">
          <Trs Trcount="7">
            <Tr RowID="1" />
            <Tr RowID="2" />
            <Tr RowID="3" />
            <Tr RowID="4" />
            <Tr RowID="5" />
            <Tr RowID="6" />
            <Tr RowID="7" />
          </Trs>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, which assumes each `Act` contains only one `Trs`:

```
declare @count int = @xml.value('count(/XML/Acts/Act)', 'int'),
        @counter int = 1;

while (@counter <= @count)
begin
    SET @xml.modify ('insert attribute TrCount {count(/XML/Acts/Act[sql:variable("@counter")]/Trs/Tr)} into (/XML/Acts/Act[sql:variable("@counter")]/Trs)[1]');

    set @counter += 1;
end
```

`insert()` can only modify a singleton, not a whole set of nodes in one go.